# IBM Watson NLC can't upload classifier with CMD or Git Bash Shell

Tags: git-bash, ibm-watson

I try to upload my classifier for IBM Watson NLC, but it does not work... It's always telling me that my username or password is not correct, but thats not the case .... Is there something what I missing ? Below you can see what I did with git bash, I just entered the command but it always returns with the error of having the wrong password or username.

```html
$ curl -u "866fe4a8-xxxxxxx2bd61bb63":"6j7xxxxxxi156" -F training_data=@industry.csv -F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",
> \"name\":\"Industry2016\"}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 36548  100   488  100 36060    247  18313  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 18561{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2018-04-17T09:31:49-05:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-DNLKUPERR occurred when accessing https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers, Tran-Id: gateway02-65905981 - Invalid UserId and/or Password. Please confirm that your credentials match the end-point you are trying to access. A common error is trying to use credentials from an experimental or beta release against a GA release or vice versa" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error response was something like you are not allowed to create classifiers or that you are at your allocation limit, then you could assume that the credentials that you are using are correct. But you are seeing an invalid credentials message, which does imply that you are using incorrect credentials.

So check that you are using the correct credentials as specified with the Natural Language Classifier service instance that you would have created inside IBM Cloud to generate the credentials. While you are there also check the endpoint. If you are not deploying the instance say in the Germany region then the endpoint will be different.